# Different results in R's `dtw` and Python's `dtw-python`

Tags: python, r, dtw

I am exploring some alternatives to compute Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) distances in Python. And I am struggling with the limited documentation about the packages I am finding...

I have explored `dtaidistance`'s `distance_fast` and `distance`; `fastdtw`'s `fastdtw` and `dtw-python`'s `dtw` functions. They are leading to different results... I am sure it is related to some default parameters that sometimes are not so clear in the documentation, but I was not able to find any explanations about...

But my question at this moment here is about `dtw-python`. Specifically, a comparison of the Python's `dtw-python` package results with the R's `dtw` package results.

They are direct equivalent each other, as indicated [here](https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/). And the major function documentation is very similar. So it is really weird...

The R code:

```
data=read.table('synthetic_control.data',header=FALSE)
library(dtw)
dtw(x=data[1,], y=data[2,] ,
               window.type= "sakoechiba", window.size= 5)$distance
dtw(x=data[2,], y=data[3,] ,
               window.type= "sakoechiba", window.size= 5)$distance
dtw(x=data[2,], y=data[600,],
               window.type= "sakoechiba", window.size= 5)$distance
dtw(x=data[1,], y=data[600,],
               window.type= "sakoechiba", window.size= 5)$distance
dtw(x=data[3,], y=data[600,],
               window.type= "sakoechiba", window.size= 5)$distance
```

Results:

> [1] 42.181
> [1] 35.09292
> [1] 105.0999
> [1] 110.9285
> [1] 105.9934

(Edit: the above values are Euclidian distances)

---

The Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
data =  pd.read_csv("synthetic_control.data", 
                    header=None,delimiter=r"\s+")
from dtw import *
print(dtw(x=data_a.loc[0], y=data_a.loc[1] ,
               window_args= {"window_type": "sakoechiba", "window_size": 5},
               keep_internals=True).distance)
print(dtw(data_a.loc[1], data_a.loc[2] ,
               window_args= {"window_type": "sakoechiba", "window_size": 5},
               keep_internals=True).distance)
print(dtw(data_a.loc[1], data_a.loc[599] ,
               window_args= {"window_type": "sakoechiba", "window_size": 5},
               keep_internals=True).distance)
print(dtw(data_a.loc[0], data_a.loc[599] ,
               window_args= {"window_type": "sakoechiba", "window_size": 5},
               keep_internals=True).distance)
print(dtw(data_a.loc[2], data_a.loc[599] ,
               window_args= {"window_type": "sakoechiba", "window_size": 5},
               keep_internals=True).distance)
```

Results:

> 166.58120000000002
> 165.87640000000005
> 647.89322
> 604.29862
> 663.3971200000001

---

The example above use synthetic dataset available [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Synthetic+Control+Chart+Time+Series), and each row represent a time serie.

As pointed above, the intention was to set the same parameters (windows type, windows size)... and the defaults appears to be the same for both python and R... What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Well, the first question is:  which of these is the correct (or approximately correct) answer?  Please tell us that.    Have you manually verified that the different indexing (start at 1 vs start at 0) is in fact pulling the same data values?

Comment: yes, the indexing are correct, and lead to same values...

Comment: ... for example, with vectors s1 = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0] and s2 = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] the result in python is 2.0 and for R 3...

Comment: Plot those 2 time-series.  I'm not sure any DTW algo will converge to a sensible result.

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthoft, thank you for taking a look at the question. The last short example is based in a toy example available at one of the dtw packages... (maybe tsdist, do not remember). The data I included in the question is longer...

Comment: I am really intrigued by the difference in the results for two packages which I understand would be a counterpart in another language (and developed by same individuals), when parameters are set to be equivalent. I am not pointing the comparisons here, but the dtw-python results match the results delivered by R's dtwclust package...  and the R's dtw result matches R's TSclust's results...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, in fact, the R results are simple Euclidean Distances... And the window parameters are completely ignored in both codes... (no change happens changing them...)

Answer (score 1):

I think I can shed some light on the differences (disclaimer: dtaidistance co-author).

The differences can be explained by a different interpretation of the DTW algorithm.  The DTW algorithm as defined in multiple papers and on Wikipedia:

Given two series x and y with length m, n, respectively.

dtw[i,j] = d(x[i], y[j]) + min(dtw[i-1,j], dtw[i-1,j-1], dtw[i,j-1])

where d is often absolute cost |x[i]-yj]| or quadratic (x[i]-yj])^2 cost. In case of quadratic, we can do dtw[:,:] = sqrt(dtw[:,:]) to have the results again in the original magnitude. The final DTW distance is dtw[m,n].

Quadratic distance is the more popular choice as it better penalizes large deviations [1,2] and also the choice in the dtaidistance toolbox.

This can be verified by computing the cumulative cost on the warped time series. I'll use your series as example:

```py
x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

from dtaidistance import dtw
d = dtw.distance(x,y)
print(f'DTW = {d}')  # DTW = 1.4142135623730951
x_warped = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
y_warped = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
d_warped = math.sqrt(sum([(xi - yi)**2 for xi,yi in zip(x_warped, y_warped)]))
print(f'DTW = {d_warped}')  # DTW = 1.4142135623730951
```

Python-dtw choses absolute cost, because the default choice for `dist_method` is 'euclidean'. Thus even if you give Euclidean as argument, because d(a,b)=sqrt((a-b)^2))=|a-b|, it is still absolute value. See this line in the code:
https://github.com/DynamicTimeWarping/dtw-python/blob/0aec342c558fbb601a530890e963e5106c60564c/dtw/dtw.py#L364

For example:

```py
import python_dtw
d = python_dtw.dtw(x,y).distance
print(f'DTW = {d}')  # DTW = 2.0
x_warped = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
y_warped = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
d_warped = sum([(xi - yi) for xi,yi in zip(x_warped, y_warped)])
print(f'DTW = {d_warped}')  # DTW = 2
```

With respect to fastdtw, this is an approximate method. So the result will likely differ from the exact output. In most cases, however, standard DTW is faster than fastdtw because it is easier to optimize for a cpu (e.g. dtaidistance is >100x faster than fastdtw). See also the comparison by Wu and Keogh [3].

[1] Keogh, E. (2002). Exact indexing of dynamic time warping. In 28th International Conference on Very Large Data Bases.
[2] A. Mueen and E. Keogh. Extracting optimal performance from dynamic time warping. KDD Tutorial, 2016.
[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.11246

Comment: thank you so much for taking time to answer the question in a so detailed manner and passing thoroughly on the differences among the major python packages. It really makes a point and bring clarity on the differences on the packages, thank you. Thought still intrigued how R and python counterpart of same package can differ in approach/choices, this is really a very explanatory answer, thank you!

Comment: For me they give the same result:
a <- c(0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
b <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
r = dtw(a,b)
r$distance
Returns 2 as expected. If you by accident transposed the inputs, it is 2.82427. Maybe that happened?

Comment: thank you, that's correct, the data is structured as rows, and I needed to `unlist ()` them in R! Function is not planned to convert it automatically to something like numeric vector/array, and apparently there is also no kind of verification in this sense... so, instead of the error, I get a different number! Thank you...